# DirectX camera position

Tags: c++, camera, directx

I can't seem to find any information on how a camera's world space position can be initially set or how exactly it is being set. I would like to be able to initially set the position but I'm not sure where I can do this. Thanks for any help with this. Here is the code I've been looking at from Frank Luna's books.

```
float x = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*cosf(mTheta);
float z = mRadius*sinf(mPhi)*sinf(mTheta);
float y = mRadius*cosf(mPhi);

// Build the view matrix.
XMVECTOR pos    = XMVectorSet(x, y, z, 1.0f);
XMVECTOR target = XMVectorZero();
XMVECTOR up     = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

XMMATRIX V = XMMatrixLookAtLH(pos, target, up);
```

Comment: By setting `mPhi` and `mTheta`? I don't understand the question...

Comment: Could you tell me why or point me to an explanation of why we are using these trig functions and multiplication to calculate the eye position? Thanks

Comment: To [define a position on a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Comment: Is this only useful for a camera to rotate around a stationary point as opposed to a first person style camera?

Comment: I should have added that the variables are set as follows <code>mTheta(1.5f *MathHelper::Pi), mPhi(0.25f *MathHelper::Pi), mRadius(5.0f)</code>